# Why can I not directly refer to a namespace that I can import?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, vs-web-application-project

I'm working with a 3rd party library with a namespace called `Telerik.Webcontrols`.  The library is in a web site project that I am in the process of converting to a web application project.

`Telerik.WebControls` contains a class called `RadAjaxControl`.

In the original web site project, I have code that looks like this:

```
public sub page_load(...)
    dim foo as Telerik.Webcontrols.RadAjaxControl
```

Once I convert to a web application project, it says that `Telerik.Webcontrols` doesn't exist.

However, the truly bizarre thing is that the following code does compile:

```
imports Telerik.WebControls

public sub page_load(...)
    dim foo as RadAjaxControl
```

What could possibly be going on here?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm stating the obvious, but this happened to me once and it was all because I happened to have another public class with the same name as the imported namespace or class name. So, double check to be sure. It's times like this that I wish I could post anonymously to avoid embarrassment of my past antics...

Answer (score 2):

Watch your casing: `Telerik.Webcontrols != Telerik.WebControls`

Comment: I'm a c# dev so I could be wrong, but isn't VB.NET case insensitive?

Comment: VB.NET itself is indeed case insensitive, but I am not sure what would happen if the third party library (possibly written i C#) mixes up the casing of the namespace between classes. Maybe some VB.NET shark can help us here?

Comment: @Daniel - I believe that although VB.net is not case sensitive per say, misusing case on namespaces can cause it some issues. See this answer on an asp.net thread: http://forums.asp.net/t/896345.aspx/1?namespace .

Answer (score 1):

I would remove and re-add the reference to Telerik. Or drop a new Telerik control on to your page. This should clear up the missing namespace.